# How can I keep DB connection always alive in HANA Studio?

Tags: database, connection, hana

As I am using HANA studio on Eclipse, if I just leave it for a small amount of time, after I return and execute something, it freezes. I guess this is because of lose of the DB connection in that while. Is there any setting parameter that makes DB connection permanent by sending continuous pings or in any other manner?

Answer (score 2):

in HANA Studio

- Right Click on your System -> Administration
- Tab Configuration -> expand indexserver.ini -> idle_connection_timeout
- Change the parameter

Then restart your system from HANA Studio